# Client-side nodeJS pass-through stream for audio streaming

Tags: node.js, client-side, audio-streaming, nodejs-stream

We work on a streaming utility, able of streaming a music of Youtube for example.

We did a first shot using `NodeJS` and [YTDL](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core). It went perfectly ok, except the fact that the stream would go from Youtube to our server and then to client, and we would like to make the stream directly from Youtube to the client.

For that i used `browserify` on `YTDL`, so now i can get a pass-through nodeJS stream on client-side, but i cant see how to use it as it without using `nodeJS` method like `.pipe()`, neither how to get the stream raw data and write it to a temporary mp3 file.

I know its not really a trivial method but that's the first time i do something like this and i'm not very much experienced on the question, so if you have any other methods that works i would happily listen to them.